# How internet domains works from practical owners perspective?

Tags: internet, domain

If I pay for internet domain, for example `mysuperspecialdomain.com`. Get I some password,
so i can enter to some configuration site and here can i set `mysuperspecialdomain.com` to open `mypage.someserver.com`?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that. But in essence you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More or less.

First, you contact a [*registrar*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar) like NameCheap, 1&1, 101Domains, GoDaddy, etc. (I personally use NameCheap, but there are lots of registrars) and register a domain with them. This usually involves creating an account on their website, searching for the domain that you want, and if it's available, buying it through some shopping-cart based checkout system.

The *registrar* will contact the [*registry operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registry) for the TLD ([Top Level Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) - the `*.com` or `*.net` or `*.org` part of the url) and register the domain you want, and assigns it to use the registrar's nameservers. At this point the domain is "registered" and ready for use.

The *registrar* then typically provides a web-based control panel which allows you to create DNS records, such as a `CNAME` record that points `mysuperspecialdomain.com` to `mypage.someserver.com` or an `A` record that points `mysuperspecialdomain.com` to `127.0.0.1`.

The registrar will typically require that you keep your contact information up to date, and send out reminders when your domain is about to expire.

If you are unhappy with with your registrar, it's possible to transfer the domain to a different registrar. This will take a few days and has several (usually time-based) restrictions to make sure that you're really sure you want to transfer. (This is to help prevent domains from being stolen)

If you want to use your own DNS servers, you can usually configure this in the registrar's control panel, at which point you will be responsible for managing your own DNS nameservers (this is very advanced, I would not recommend this unless you have far more experience with DNS then you appear to have. The registrar usually will have well-tested nameservers already.)